# Basic Calculator - event binding using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am completely new to the JavaScript .When I am looking to get the value to the button its get failed. I already given the `setEvent.Like getEle();`
And also bind the click function, now I want to get the input values and perform mathematical calculations.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
      <title>Simple Calculator</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calculator.css">
    </head>
 <body>
    <div id="container" >
       <div class="calculator">
           <ul>
              <li>
                  <div id="display">
                    <span id="math"></span>
                    <span id="number"></span>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="input" value="7">7</button>
                <button class="input" value="8">8</button>
                <button class="input" value="9">9</button>
                <button class="control" value="/">&#247;</button>
                <button class="undo" value="-1">&#8592;</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="input" value="4">4</button>
                <button class="input" value="5">5</button>
                <button class="input" value="6">6</button>
                <button class="control" value="*">&#215;</button>
                <button class="clear">C</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="input" value="1">1</button>
                <button class="input" value="2">2</button>
                <button class="input" value="3">3</button>
                <button class="control" value="-">-</button>
                <button class="control" value="%">%</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="input size2" value="0">0</button>
                <button class="input" value=".">&#8729;</button>
                <button class="control" value="+">+</button>
                <button class="submit">=</button>
                  </li>
               </ul>
          </div>
       </div>
   </body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="calculator.js"></script>
  </html>
```

JavaScript

```
function setEvent(evt, ele, callback) {
   var ele = getEle(ele);
    if (ele.length === undefined) {
    ele.addEventListener(evt, callback, false);        
    } else if(ele.length > 0) {
       for (var i=0; i<ele.length; i++) {
        ele[i].addEventListener(evt, callback, false);
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function getEle(ele) {
  var _idf = ele.charAt(0);
   if (_idf == "#") {
    var _ele = document.getElementById(ele.substr(1));
    return _ele;
  } else if(_idf == ".") {
    var _els = document.getElementsByClassName(ele.substr(1));
    return _els;
  }
  return ele;
 }

setEvent("click", ".input", function() { 
  console.log(this.value);
 });

setEvent("click", ".control", function() { 
  console.log(this.value);
 });
```

Comment: I put this in a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kkhh71ct/) and it seems to work ok, What exactly do you expect and what unexpected do you get?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9n8eeob1/1/ - looks fine

Comment: how can i print these values in #display and its calculations

Comment: After your updated question: You are on the correct way. You can get the value from the buttons that have been clicked, in the same way you can use that `this.value` to add it to `#number` ...... **hint**: `document.getElementById("#number").innerHTML = this.value`

Comment: _sidenote_: instead of your function `getEle` you can use [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: but I have already binded the elements like var _ele = document.getElementById(ele.substr(1)); and var _els = document.getElementsByClassName(ele.substr(1));

Comment: function setVal(ele, val) {
 var _ele = getEle(ele);
 if (_ele.length > 0) {
    for (var i=0; i<_ele.length; i++){
       _ele[i].value = val;
    }
 } else {
     _ele.value = val;
 }
  }

Comment: this is for setting values

Comment: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkhh71ct/2/) to help you a bit in the right direction ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function setEvent(evt, ele, callback) {
    var ele = getEle(ele);
    if (ele.length === undefined) {
        ele.addEventListener(evt, callback, false);        
    } else if(ele.length > 0) {
        for (var i=0; i<ele.length; i++) {
            ele[i].addEventListener(evt, callback, false);
        }
    }
    return false;
    }

function getEle(ele) {
    var _idf = ele.charAt(0);
    if (_idf == "#") {
        var _ele = document.getElementById(ele.substr(1));
        return _ele;
    } else if(_idf == ".") {
        var _els = document.getElementsByClassName(ele.substr(1));
        return _els;
    }
    return ele;
    }

function getInnerHtml(id) {
     return document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;                   
   }
function getValue(elem) {
  return elem.value;
  }

setEvent("click", ".input", function() { 
  console.log(this.value);
  var _num = getInnerHtml("number");
  _num = _num + "" + getValue(this);
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = _num;
    });

setEvent("click", ".control", function() { 
  console.log(this.value);
  var _num1 = document.getElementById("number").innerHTML;
  _num1 = _num1 + "" + this.value;
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = _num1;
  });
setEvent("click", ".clear", function() { 
  console.log(this.value);
  var _num1 = document.getElementById("number").innerHTML;
  _num1 = "";
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = _num1;
  });
setEvent("click", ".submit", function() { 
  console.log(this.value);
   var _num1 = document.getElementById("number").innerHTML;
  _num1 = eval( _num1 + "" + getValue(this));
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = _num1;
  });
```

Hope this will work out.

Answer (score 0):

You can print the values to the screen by using document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = this.value.

Notie that it is not jquery, when calling getElementById you don't do("#id") only ("id"), JavaScript will match the string with the desired Id.

In jquery, it is much like the behavior of css, so in order to find ID you don't do getElementById instead, you just do

`//$ means jquery 
$("#id")`

which is equivalent to java script's getElementById.