# Javascript - Sending Signature-Pad results to Flask

Tags: javascript, flask, signaturepad

I'm using the [signature-pad JavaScript](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) library to have people digitally sign documents (this is just for testing, nothing legally binding, etc.) but I'm having a hard time passing the signature result back to Flask/Python from JS.

The following code is my HTML form, it submits the `form.stu_name` field perfectly, and even triggers my JS to "submit"(meaning the code executes and a new window opens displaying the signature) but I'm not sure how to submit the JS result back to Flask - see the second code block example for more.

```
<div class="container">
    {% from "_formhelper.html" import render_field %}
    <form id="upload-form" method="POST" action="/sixth_form/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <dl>
      {{render_field(form.stu_name)}}
        </dl>
        <p>Student Signature</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/grey.jpeg') }}" width=400 height=200 />
  <canvas id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad" width=400 height=200></canvas>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="clear" type="Button">Clear</button>
</div>
<br>
    <p><input id="finalsub" type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here's the script itself, when run it opens a new window with the result of the signature presented as an URI encoded image (that part is fine, I can decode it later in Python), what I need help with - Instead of opening a new window I want to submit the image back to Flask and then store it in a variable so I can append it to another image. I'm not very knowledgeable with JS, so any suggestions are very welcome!

```
<script>
var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(document.getElementById('signature-pad'), {
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
  penColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
});
var saveButton = document.getElementById('finalsub');
var cancelButton = document.getElementById('clear');

saveButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var data = signaturePad.toDataURL('image/png');

// Send data to server instead...
  window.open(data);
});

cancelButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  signaturePad.clear();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20107080/5854907) seems to be what you're looking for. This is using `jQuery` however. To do this in pure JavaScript look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31115081/5854907). Then to access the file you would use `flask.request.files`.

A blind (read: untested) example would be:

```
$(function() {
    $('#upload-file-btn').click(function() {
        var data = signaturePad.toDataURL('image/png');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/uploadUrl',
            data: data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('Success!');
            },
        });
    });
});
```

> Now in your flask's endpoint view function, you can access the file's
>   data via flask.request.files.

**Note:** As I said this is untested, and I don't know if the `ajax` config (for instance making the request synchronous or setting `contentType` to false) are all necessary. My intuition would be to rewrite it like this:

#### NOT TESTED

```
$(function() {
    $('#upload-file-btn').click(function() {
        var data = signaturePad.toDataURL('image/png');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/uploadUrl',
            data: data,
            contentType: 'image/png'
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log('Success!');
        }).fail(function(data) {
            console.log('Fail!');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this! This definitely got me on the right track. Much appreciated.

Comment: @BrettJ, do you mind sharing your solution for that? I am new to flask and js and wanted to do something similar to what you asked. I have followed  Allie's suggestion. I do get the signal sent to flask but when reading with request.files("data") or request.values.get("data") it simply returns a None. Probably missing something simple!

Comment: @Mencia this was a while ago but I found the files I was working on. I placed them on Github https://github.com/MingyJ/signature - I can't promise they're pretty or complete but I do remember it working :)

Comment: @BrettJ Thank you very much!